# Why is the server not sending the client response back in a client-server reactor pattern?

Tags: c, client-server, project-reactor

react_server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "reactor.h"
#include <ctype.h>

void handleClientReact(int fd) {
    printf("Client connected to fd %d\n", fd);

    char buffer[1024];
    ssize_t bytesRead = recv(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    if (bytesRead == -1) {
        perror("recv");
        close(fd);
        return;
    } else if (bytesRead == 0) {
        // Client disconnected
        printf("Client disconnected from fd %d\n", fd);
        close(fd);
        return;
    }

    // Process the client's request and generate a response
    // For example, let's assume we convert the received message to uppercase
    for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++) {
        buffer[i] = toupper(buffer[i]);
    }

    printf("Received data from client: %s\n", buffer);

    // Send the response back to the client
    ssize_t bytesSent = send(fd, buffer, bytesRead, 0);
    if (bytesSent == -1) {
        perror("send");
        close(fd);
        return;
    }

    printf("Response sent to client\n");

    close(fd);
}

int createListeningSocket() {
    // Create a listening socket and return its file descriptor
    int listeningSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;
    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(9034);
    bind(listeningSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress));
    listen(listeningSocket, 5);
    return listeningSocket;
}

int main() {
    Reactor* reactor = createReactor();

    // Create a listening socket and add it to the reactor
    int listeningSocket = createListeningSocket();
    addFd(reactor, listeningSocket, handleClientReact);

    // Start the reactor in a separate thread
    pthread_create(&reactor->reactorThread, NULL, startReactor, reactor);

    // Wait for the reactor thread to finish
    WaitFor(reactor);

    free(reactor);

    return 0;
}
```

reactor.c

```
#include "reactor.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>

Reactor* createReactor() {
    Reactor* reactor = (Reactor*)malloc(sizeof(Reactor));
    reactor->numFds = 0;
    reactor->running = 0;
    return reactor;
}

void handleClientReact(int fd) {
    printf("Client connected to fd %d\n", fd);

    char buffer[1024];
    ssize_t bytesRead = recv(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    if (bytesRead == -1) {
        perror("recv");
        close(fd);
        return;
    } else if (bytesRead == 0) {
        // Client disconnected
        printf("Client disconnected from fd %d\n", fd);
        close(fd);
        return;
    }

    // Process the client's request and generate a response
    // For example, let's assume we convert the received message to uppercase
    for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++) {
        buffer[i] = toupper(buffer[i]);
    }

    printf("Received data from client: %s\n", buffer);

    // Send the response back to the client
    ssize_t bytesSent = send(fd, buffer, bytesRead, 0);
    if (bytesSent == -1) {
        perror("send");
        close(fd);
        return;
    }

    printf("Response sent to client\n");

    close(fd);
}

void stopReactor(Reactor* reactor) {
    reactor->running = 0;
}

void* startReactor(void* arg) {
    Reactor* reactor = (Reactor*)arg;
    reactor->running = 1;

    int listeningSocket = reactor->fdHandlers[0].fd;  // Obtain the listening socket from the first fdHandler

    while (reactor->running) {
        int numReady = poll(reactor->pollFds, reactor->numFds, -1);
        if (numReady == -1) {
            perror("poll");
            continue;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < reactor->numFds; ++i) {
            if (reactor->pollFds[i].fd == listeningSocket) {
                int newSocket = accept(listeningSocket, NULL, NULL);
                if (newSocket == -1) {
                    perror("accept");
                    continue;
                }
                addFd(reactor, newSocket, handleClientReact);
            } else if (reactor->pollFds[i].revents & POLLIN) {
                reactor->fdHandlers[i].handler(reactor->pollFds[i].fd);
            }
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}

void addFd(Reactor* reactor, int fd, handler_t handler) {
    if (reactor->numFds >= MAX_CLIENTS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Max number of clients reached\n");
        return;
    }

    reactor->fdHandlers[reactor->numFds].fd = fd;
    reactor->fdHandlers[reactor->numFds].handler = handler;

    reactor->pollFds[reactor->numFds].fd = fd;
    reactor->pollFds[reactor->numFds].events = POLLIN;

    reactor->numFds++;
}

void WaitFor(Reactor* reactor) {
    pthread_join(reactor->reactorThread, NULL);
}
```

reactor.h

```
#ifndef REACTOR_H
#define REACTOR_H

#include <pthread.h>
#include <poll.h>

#define MAX_CLIENTS 10

typedef void (*handler_t)(int fd);

typedef struct {
    int fd;
    handler_t handler;
} FdHandler;

typedef struct {
    FdHandler fdHandlers[MAX_CLIENTS];
    struct pollfd pollFds[MAX_CLIENTS];
    int numFds;
    pthread_t reactorThread;
    int running;
} Reactor;

Reactor* createReactor();
void stopReactor(Reactor* reactor);
void* startReactor(void* arg);
void addFd(Reactor* reactor, int fd, handler_t handler);
void WaitFor(Reactor* reactor);

#endif
```

makefile

```
CC = gcc CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 LDFLAGS = -L./lib -lst_reactor

all: lib/libst_reactor.so react_server

lib/libst_reactor.so: reactor.o $(CC) -shared -o lib/libst_reactor.so reactor.o

reactor.o: reactor.c reactor.h $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -fPIC -c reactor.c

react_server: react_server.o $(CC) -o react_server react_server.o $(LDFLAGS)

react_server.o: react_server.c reactor.h $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c react_server.c

clean: rm -f .o lib/.so react_server

.PHONY: all clean
```

I'm expecting that the server should send just as the clients response and the client should be able to disconnect from the server using ctrl +c
i'm using reactor pattern
the server is not showing any connection succesful or client connected response on server side

How can I implement a server using the reactor pattern in such a way that it sends the same response as the client and allows the client to disconnect using Ctrl+C? Currently, the server is not displaying any successful connection or client connected response.

Comment: The makefile doesn't look right. The compilation commands should be on the next line after the dependency lists.

Comment: Did you null-terminate the received buffer before passing it to `printf()`?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).